# Total sum of values in an ArrayList

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim arrLst As New ArrayList
 Dim dblVal as Double
```

this `arrLst` constists of n number of values(`Double`)

at present i use the following piece of code to calculate the sum of 
 values in `arrLst`

```
        For i = 0 To arrLst .Count - 1
            If dblVal = 0.0 Then
                dblVal = arrLst .Item(i)
            Else
                dblVal = dblVal + arrLst.Item(i)
            End If
        Next
```

as `arrList.Sum()` is not available in `VB.NET`, is there any other method to do the same job ?

Comment: `arrList.Sum()`? Edit: this is c#, not sure if vb has this too but I presume it would

Comment: Use the extension method sum()

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918069.aspx

Comment: why the if statement?

Comment: @Sayse `arrList.Sum()` not available

Comment: use arrLst.OfType(Of Double).Sum

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, first of all, an `ArrayList` is not a good choice to store values of the same type. You should rather use a `List(Of Double)`, then each value doesn't have to be cast to double when you access it.

Anyhow, you can make your code a lot simpler by just setting the sum to zero before you start:

```
dblVal = 0.0
For i = 0 To arrLst.Count - 1
  dblVal = dblVal + arrLst.Item(i)
Next
```

(I know that the variable is zero by default when you declare it, so you could actually skip setting it to zero, but it's good to actually set values that the code relies on.)

Using `For each` and the `+=` operator it gets even simpler:

```
dblVal = 0.0
For Each n In arrLst
  dblVal += n
Next
```

You can also use the method `Sum` to add all the values, but as you use an `ArrayList` you have to make it a collection of doubles first:

```
dblVal = arrLst.Cast(of Double).Sum()
```

Comment: [+1 from my side] WELL EXPLAINED !! and i have changed it to `List(Of Double)` thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dblVal = 0
arrLst.OfType(Of Double)().ToList(Of Double)().ForEach(Function(dbl) dblVal += dbl)
```

Comment: Good and Clean Solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
double doubleSum = doubleList.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
```

Comment: This looks like Java to me and not like vb.net.