# How do I compute the average of an array?

Tags: vb.net

Given an array of integers, how can I compute the average of that array in VB.NET?

The array initialization is below:

```
Public Class Form1        
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click    
        Dim numbers() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Which part you have problem with? Summing numbers from a an array, or dividing? :o

Comment: Question is not clear. Also, how is this a C# question?

Comment: Just displaying them and summing the numbers together and finding the average? (Sorry I'm new to programming)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651159/total-sum-of-values-in-an-arraylist

Comment: Mean, median, mode? There's more than one way to skin a cat. Also, could you not have at least Googled this or tried to do it yourself?

Comment: `numbers.ToList().Average()`, there you are done :) kidding `numbers.Average`, thats much better :P

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  They are all easy.  Here are two.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim numbers() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    Dim sum As Integer = 0

    'method 1 - more or less the way you'd do it by hand
    For Each n In numbers
        sum += n
    Next
    Dim average As Double = sum / numbers.Length
    MessageBox.Show(average.ToString())

    'method 2 - just use the array's extension method
    MessageBox.Show(numbers.Average())
End Sub
```

Comment: No need for the `New List(Of)`, just call `numbers.Average` extention... `numbers` is already a sequence of Integers, no need to create a list when you already have something to enumerate... Also turn `Option Strict On`, you have some implicit conversion errors. Thoughts?

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(autogenerated stuff) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim numbers() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
   Dim Average As Integer

'add up all numbers in array (the number in parentheses is the index, which starts at 0)
   Average = (numbers(0) + numbers(1) + numbers(2) + numbers(3) + numbers(4) _
              + numbers(5)) / 6
```

Then, depending on whether you want to display it in a label or a message box, you would use either

```
Me.Label1.Text = "The average of these numbers is " & Average
```

or

```
MessageBox.Show("The average of these numbers is " & Average)
```